# Listar 3 itens lado a lado

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou querendo fazer uma listagem de itens sequencias só que com 3 colunas, criei uma lógica de impar ou par, para fazer a listagem lado a lado, no caso 2 colunas...

Mas agora tenho que fazer uma listagem de 3 itens por linha...
A imagem abaixo mostra como é a ideia, mas só que a coluna 3 está repetindo os itens da coluna 2.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="row p30-top">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php
                            if(have_posts()) : the_post();
                                $i = 0;
                                $content = explode("<li>", get_the_content());
                                foreach($content as $row) : 
                                    if($i % 2 == 0) : 
                        ?>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"><?= $row ?></div>
                        <?php else : ?>
                                    <div class="col-md-4"><?= $row ?></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4"><?= $row ?></div>
                                </div>
                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                    $i++;
                                endforeach;
                                if($i % 2 != 0) { echo '</div>'; }
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

`Exemplo de como estou implementando o código:. (Acima)`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função **arr_chunk** para quebrar a array em pedaços de 3:

```
arr_chunk(array,quantidade);
```

Assim você já cria a estrutura e não lida com os índices:

```
<div class="row p30-top">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <?php
        if(have_posts()) : the_post();
        $content = explode("<li>", get_the_content());
        $content = array_chunk($content,3);

        foreach($content as $row){
            echo '<div class="row">';
            foreach($row as $col){
                echo  '<div class="col-md-4">' . $col . '</div>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Isso deve resolver.